# Replacing figure with .mp4

Tags: media9, video

I want to replace a figure with a video file (.mp4) using the media9 package however I don't know in which environment to place it. Can someone give me an example such that it still looks like a standard figure with caption etc.

Comment: If some image is included inside a `figure` environment, replace `\includegraphics{...}` with the media inclusion command from the `media9` package. BTW, always provide a complete example [**(↗MWE)**](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that compiles such that we have something to work with.